# Recommendation for a Ryzen cooler

Tags: cooling

Could someone please recommend a cooler for a Ryzen AM4 motherboard (ASUS Prime X370-PRO). I need one that comes with a complete mounting kit (i.e. the first step in attaching is to remove the kit that comes with the motherboard, that is two bits of plastic on its top side next to the socket, and presumably a backing plate underneath).

To be clear, the parts that I don't have are visible in the photo at the top of https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-X370-PRO/ I have just holes in the motherboard instead of the four screws around the CPU socket, and the two bits of plastic that they attach.

Many thanks in advance. Suggestions for where to find a replacement mounting kit that should have come with the board very welcome too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://assets.coolermaster.com/landing/am4-socket-ready/v2/download/RR-AM4B-H212-S1.pdf

That is a link to the installation instructions for installing a Coolermaster after-market cooler. It lists the following models as compatible with an AM4 socket:

- MasterAir Pro 4
- MasterAir Pro 3
- Hyper 412 Series
- Hyper 212 EVO
- Hyper 212 X

The instructions specifically state that you need to remove those two plastic brackets and the screws, using the backplate and the holes in the motherboard to install the cooler instead of those brackets.

I'm certain that if you looked at other cooler manufacturers like BeQuiet or Noctua you could find something with similar after-market brackets if none of the listed options meet your other unlisted requirements, whatever they may be.

I will also recommend contacting Asus and having them ship you a spare bracket, as I'm not able to find any online that aren't the usual litany of poorly priced ebay listings. Your motherboard should have come with that, and if your aftermarket cooler were to break or something that backup option should be available to you. You're the customer, get what you paid for.

Comment: Asus is not known for the quality of their customer support.

Comment: @Mark I haven't had any below average experiences with them, but they definitely nave never blown me out of the water. That's still no reason to simply let it slide. Letting those little things go contributes to bad customer service in the first place. You can't make improvements with no data and no feedback.

Comment: @jcam3 Many thanks, and sorry for not upvoting your answer. For some reason it won't let me even though I am able to accept it.

Comment: @user6537 No worries, it's probably part of the site rules. You need to hit a reputation breakpoint in some of the stack exchange communities in order to gain certain privileges. Glad I was able to help. Quick edit: It's not publicly visible but I did get the rep bonus for your vote, so definitely don't be discouraged from tossing points at answers that help you solve a problem.